# Multiple uses of replaceAll() String method

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

I am doing some text preprocessing and I am using the replaceAll() method at least 10 times. This is starting to get inefficient I am afraid.

My code is like:

```
text = text.replaceAll(regex1, "rStr");
text = text.replaceAll(regex2, "rStr2");
.
.
.
text = text.replaceAll(regexn, "rStrn");
```

I thought I'd use StringBuilder in order to avoid making new strings all the time, but I didn't notice much difference.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(text.replaceAll(regex1, "rStr"));
sb.replace(0, sb.length(), sb.toString().replaceAll(regex2, "rStr2"));
.
.
.
sb.replace(0, sb.length(), sb.toString().replaceAll(regexn, "rStrn"));
```

Any ideas how to make this code more efficient?

Comment: It might help if you'd tag the question with a language you're using - Java isn't it?

Comment: If you are only calling the replaceAll() method ~10 times, this is a very small efficiency problem which is why you didn't notice much difference.

Comment: Could you tell us a little more about why you're doing so many substring replacements?

Comment: Sure, I need to clean a text from multiple and different unwanted features such as emoticons, LOLs, numbers and more. So since there isn't a single pattern to catch all these cases, I think I need to do this.

Comment: Ah. If you can get away with a single replacement, you can speed things up with alternation. But really, what you might want here is Aho Corasick (which funny enough, works a bit like a dumbed-down regex).

Comment: Yes actually both my regular expressions and the replacing strings (most of them) are different. Thanks, didn't know about that I'll give it a look.

Comment: If you can change your regexs to just strings, Aho Corasick is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your patterns, you can get decent improvements from precompiling them. `replaceAll` has to do something like `Pattern.compile(patternStr).matcher(this).replaceAll(replacement)`. It doesn't cache the `Pattern`, so if you compile it just once, you'll see improvements, provided that code gets called more than once.

If you can, use `String.replace()` rather than `String.replaceAll()`, but it sounds a bit like you need the pattern.

Comment: Yes indeed I need the pattern. Thanks, I'll give it a try and let you know a little later.

Answer (score -2):

Try to not use regular expressions at all. In java, that is mostly:

- replaceAll
- split
- Pattern and Matcher classes

If you can use the substring method or indexOf methods instead, do that!

Comment: I hate this advice. Precompiled patterns are faster than you'd think, but more importantly, if they're readable, you'll have code that's a lot cleaner and less brittle than substring hell.

Comment: split() doesn't use regular expressions for regular expressions that are just string literals. It's an optimization in the implementation for a common use case.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html Yes split uses regular expressions I do it all the time with [\n\r]+. Regular expressions are way overused when they shouldn't be. I would suggest at the least do a contains call prior to a replaceAll so the regular expression can be avoided in some circumstances. Doing that alone speeds up my code a lot.

Comment: Reread what I said; split doesn't use patterns for something like split("foo"). It does for "\\s+". I tend to find they're they're *underused*, and people resort to parsing by hand because they either don't know regular expressions or are prematurely optimizing. Real-world performance problems are almost always around disk IO, network IO, or frequently-run algorithms on large data sets. But if you're not precompiling your patterns, I could see why you'd think they're slow.

Comment: I get what you're saying. But to my point of this post, replaceAll creates horror stories. I advise against it.